# Python - Display Entered text in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to write a simple Tkinter form. It should read user's input, and then display the result when clicking a button.

However, my code doesn't return anything. I found this thread:
[Python Tkinter Entry get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662844/python-tkinter-entry-get)

But still nothing I do returns me the text that users entered.

This is my script. Your help is appreciated:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont


class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        # setting title
        root.title("undefined")
        # setting window size
        global result
        width = 600
        height = 500
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        LineEdit = tk.Entry(root)
        LineEdit["borderwidth"] = "2px"
        LineEdit.place(x=250, y=50, width=289, height=30)
        result = LineEdit.get()

        LineLabel = tk.Label(root)
        LineLabel["text"] = "Enter Your Input:"
        LineLabel.place(x=60, y=50, width=177, height=30)

        GoButton = tk.Button(root)
        GoButton["text"] = "Analyze"
        GoButton.place(x=170, y=130, width=195, height=58)
        GoButton["command"] = self.DisplayInput

    def DisplayInput(self):
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the content of `LineEdit` inside `DisplayInput()`. But you need to change `LineEdit` to instance variable `self.LineEdit`, otherwise it cannot be accessed inside `DisplayInput()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont


class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        # setting title
        root.title("undefined")
        # setting window size
        #global result
        width = 600
        height = 500
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.LineEdit = tk.Entry(root)
        self.LineEdit["borderwidth"] = "2px"
        self.LineEdit.place(x=250, y=50, width=289, height=30)
        #result = LineEdit.get()

        LineLabel = tk.Label(root)
        LineLabel["text"] = "Enter Your Input:"
        LineLabel.place(x=60, y=50, width=177, height=30)

        GoButton = tk.Button(root)
        GoButton["text"] = "Analyze"
        GoButton.place(x=170, y=130, width=195, height=58)
        GoButton["command"] = self.DisplayInput

    def DisplayInput(self):
        result = self.LineEdit.get()
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) worked like a magic. This is exactly what I wanted :)